# How to set up environment variables for node.js in NPM task

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, npm

I have `npm` task that loads concurrently, node-inspector, and node-supervisor.

```
{
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"node-inspector\" \"set NODE_PATH=.&&supervisor -n error -- ./bin/www --debug\"",
"prestart": "start chrome http://localhost:3000 http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858"
}
```

**Result:**

```
[1] set NODE_PATH=.&&supervisor -n error -- ./bin/www --debug exited with code 0
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] Node Inspector v0.12.7
[0] Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

But when I'm trying `localhost:3000` I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**QUESTION 1:** How I can pass `NODE_PATH=.` (or any other ENV variable) to supervisor - so my node runs correctly?

**QUESTION 2:** Or maybe you know, how to organize two watch tasks within `npm` scripts? for example: `node-supervisor` and `node-inspector`

**Note1:** If I run `set NODE_PATH=.&&supervisor -n error -- ./bin/www --debug` directly from command line - works well.

**Note2:** If I run `npm start` without `NODE_PATH=.&&` it works well but node error - cause it can't find modules for example `require('helpers/log')` or `require('models/user')` cause i don't want to place everything in `node_modules`.

**Stats:**

- Windows 8.1
- Node 4.4.0
- npm 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, check out the handy helper module [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

It's designed for exactly this purpose, and is easy to use. Just use `cross-env` where you'd typically use UNIX-style env, and away you go. Mine, for example, looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env DEBUG=express:router webpack-dev-server ...."
}
```